# Banners shows small on mobile and big on laptop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I have a banner code that shows banner image big enough correctly on my laptop screen but when I open the same web page on my mobile phone, it shows the banner very small in height making it narrow to read. how to resolve this issue so that I can make the banner remain the same size for laptop screen as it is currently now, but much bigger for the mobile screens?

**HTML CODE:**

```
<?php

echo "<div class=custom-banner><img src=https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/banner.gif></div>";

?>
```

```css
.custom-banner {
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class=custom-banner><img src=https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/banner.gif></div>
```

I'm using WordPress, so maybe it inherits some CSS properties from style.css of WordPress. Currently, the banner image size is 1950 x 75.

Comment: Side note: `<img src=https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/banner.gif>` should be quoted, as should `class=custom-banner`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set img width to 100% so it would be responsive. and css selector needs to be  `.custom-banner img`

```css
.custom-banner   {
      background-image: url('https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/banner.gif');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    }
    
     @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .custom-banner   {
    background-image: url('https://www.voicesofyouth.org/sites/default/files/images/2019-03/nature-3125912_960_720.jpg');
    height:400px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class=custom-banner></div>
```

Also you need to set another img with lower height for mobile this photo is not good for responsive mobile.

you can use cs like this for mobile and background image would be changed when device width is **lower than 400px**. For Example:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 .custom-banner {
    background-image: url('https://www.voicesofyouth.org/sites/default/files/images/2019-03/nature-3125912_960_720.jpg');
    }
  }
```

Comment: hi, i used width: 100% attribute now. but it still shows very small banner on mobile. here is link: https://www.garnfyndet.se

Comment: you ned to use another photo with lower width.

Comment: if I use another photo, where to put that another image2 in css?

Comment: here is the modifed version but it is still not working... 
echo "<div class='custom-banner img'><img class = 'custom-banner img' src='https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/banner.gif'></div>";

CSS CODE:
.custom-banner img{
 background-position: center center;
 position:relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 100%;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .custom-banner{
    background-image: url('https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/mbanner.gif');
  }
}

Comment: please remove img tag from html and just update `background-img` with css

Comment: ok. I have removed img tag from html so it now like this: <div class='custom-banner'><img class = 'custom-banner' src='https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/banner.gif'></div>"........... & css is: .custom-banner img{
 background-position: center center;
 position:relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 100%;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .custom-banner{
 margin-bottom: 2000em;
    background-image: url('https://www.garnfyndet.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/mbanner.gif');
  }

}

Comment: but maybe it still need something else, its not working

Comment: @ i suggest you exactly copy and paste my answer to see what happens , i hope it helpsپھکپھکچرکینوی

Comment: ok now i applied the above given code that you edited... but still not showing any effect

Comment: now exact copied code is placed,,, still not effect. the div doesn't pick the background-image here and any other attribute